# Rcpp modules - example programs not working

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to understand how `Rcpp` modules work. I tried the full example (on page 14) in the `Rcpp` [vignette](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf). However, I don't know where `fx_vec` is defined, therefore I am not able to run the full example.

Then, I tried to compile the package is `Rcpp` source code ([here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule)). I had to make the following changes to compile the package

- I had to delete the `zzz.R` file in the `R` folder.
- I had to comment the line 48 in `stdVector.cpp` (`//.method( "resize", &vec::resize`))

I am able to compile the `testRcppModule` package now (original source code [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule)), however, I am still not able to run the program `modules.R` in the `test` folder. For reference, the package I have been to compile can be found [here](https://github.com/sn248/testRcppmodule) (note that the package names varies slightly from the original name in `Rcpp`).

The error I get on running code `v <- new (vec)` in `modules.R` is as follows

```
> library(testRcppmodule)
> v <- new(vec)
Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where, resolve.msg = resolve.msg) : 
  object 'vec' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider posting on rcpp-devel with a fuller example.  What you have above is not really self-contained.

As for 'do Modules work' we offer a resounding *Sure!!* as testing them is

- part of every unit test run, see the [test script](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/unitTests/runit.Module.R) using this [fully self-contained example package](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule)
- many packages using Modules as eg my [RcppRedis](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppredis) package, my [RcppAnnoy](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppannoy) package, my [RcppCNPy](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppcnpy) package etc

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look into the examples you have suggested to better understand how `Rcpp` modules work.